# Figma plugin development - Positioning issue in elements with transform property

Tags: html, css, figma, figma-plugin

I am facing a positioning issue in Figma design to HTML & CSS conversion. The element which has transform property is not rendered as expected in HTML when compared with the Figma design. In the attached sample, plus icon is not rendered as expected. Please find the screenshots below Figma_design_reference.png - For Figma desgin file, HTML.png - HTML file with positioning issue in the plus icon
[image: Actual figma design]
[image: Figma desgin property reference]
[image: HTML with position issue]

Comment: Please provide a link to your Figma file showing the problem, so that we can help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the `transform-origin` property.

[Here you can find documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) explaining the different value for that css property.